# Get non-local host name from Google App Engine dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sockets

I'd like to get the hostname in Google App Engine when running dev_appserver.py, because GAE is making a request of an external server and that server needs to know where to send its response.

Unfortunately, the canonical Python way doesn't seem to work, being:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

The `socket` library doesn't work in GAE.

Also,

```
os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] 
os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
```

Are both localhost.

How could one get the IP that an external server would connect to GAE?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the socket package might be disabled in the GAE sandbox.

Have you tried using the request object to determine this?
http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id1

might be the most reliable way.

Comment: This works, though one probably has to add `--address=192.168.x.x` (where 192.168.x.x is the address for GAE to listen on) as an argument to `dev_appserver.py`, and connect to GAE via that address; note that SERVER_NAME:SERVER_PORT is set on the server whereas HTTP_HOST is from the client (and thus unreliable). I'm using Django instead of Webob, so `request.META['SERVER_NAME']` is the canonical way to get the correct address.